# Comparing console input from executable jar

Tags: java, jar, executable, executable-jar

So I have this executable jar file with a username and password and runs but value doesn't ever continue correctly.
Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Hello. I am a program created by Moocow9m. What is your name?");
                InputStream stream = System.in;
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream);
                String input = scanner.next();
                if (input == "armystich"){
                System.out.println("Welcome CODE NAME: ArmyStich!");
                scanner.close();
                }
                else {
                System.out.println("Hello " + input + ". Nice to meet you.");
                scanner.close();
                }
        }
    }
```

All would work except it would always return to else. Please help.

Comment: `if (input == "armystich"){` Always compare string using the `equals` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (input == "armystich"){
```

The above checks reference equality. To check for value equality, using the equals method

```
if ( input.equals("armystich") ){
```

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: That worked but how do i make it not case sensitive?

Comment: See the [API for the String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class - there is an `equalsIgnoreCase` method.